# Pandas: iterating over df rows gives strange result

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm reading text file, from lines looking like this `*  2013  6  1  0  0  0.00000000` I take information about time. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def readGPS(location):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    with open(location) as handler:
        for i, line in enumerate(handler):
            if '*  2' in line:
                #Grab Timestamp
                links = line.split()
                index = datetime.strptime(' '.join(links[1:7]), '%Y %m %d %H %M %S.%f00')
            elif 'P ' in line:
                #Grab coordinates
                link = line.split()
                nr = int(link[1])
                satX = float(link[2])
                satY = float(link[3])
                satZ = float(link[4])
                dff = pd.DataFrame([[index, str(nr), satX, satY, satZ]], columns=['Time', 'Nr_gps', 'X_gps', 'Y_gps', 'Z_gps'])
                df1 = df1.append(dff)
    return df1
```

I need to iterate over rows in `Time` column.

When I'm doing `print df1['Time']` everything is ok, I'm getting this:

```
2013-06-01 00:00:00
2013-06-01 00:00:00
2013-06-01 00:00:00
2013-06-01 00:00:00
2013-06-01 00:05:00
2013-06-01 00:05:00
2013-06-01 00:05:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

but when I try to do this

```
   for i in range(len(df1)):
        print df1.at[i, 'Time']
```

I'm getting something like this:

```
['2013-06-01T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2013-06-01T02:00:00.000000000+0200'
 '2013-06-01T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2013-06-01T02:00:00.000000000+0200'
 '2013-06-01T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2013-06-01T02:00:00.000000000+0200'
 '2013-06-01T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2013-06-01T02:00:00.000000000+0200'
 '2013-06-01T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2013-06-01T02:05:00.000000000+0200'
```

I want to check hour in every row, I thought I could do this `df1.at[i, 'Time'].hour` but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Does `print df1.iloc[i, 'Time']` work?, your error could be is that your index doesn't contain the values generated from your `range` function, i.e. your index could be float or datetime values

Comment: @EdChum it also doesn't work

Comment: What you see is just the very confusing default numpy representation for datetime64 values (in local time ..). But how do you get this? Because you don't get a list from printing it in a loop like that. Please show exactly what you have done.

Comment: Further, what pandas version do you use? (`pd.__version__`). In recent versions accessing an element like that should put it in a Timestamp and not return a datetime64 value.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what your problem was, Joris is correct the printed result is just the numpy repr for datetime64 values

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.16.2. I've just done `print df1.at[i, 'Time']`